# PHP handling fatal errors, and storing them in a file

Tags: php, error-handling

I'm using the following code to catch uncaught exceptions and errors,

```
function my_exception_handler($e) {
        $dataToStore = array("error" => $e, "server" => $_SERVER, "request" => $_REQUEST, "backtrace" => debug_backtrace());

                //Store $dataToStore in a file
}

function my_error_handler($no, $str, $file, $line) {
    $e = new ErrorException($str, $no, 0, $file, $line);
    my_exception_handler($e);
}

set_error_handler('my_error_handler');
set_exception_handler('my_exception_handler');
```

I was wondering if there is a way to make this store only FATAL ERRORS in a file, 
the $e array has a severity which is always 0 apparently.

Comment: You could always parse the `error_log` and grep for fatals.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need `register_shutdown_function` for this task:

```
register_shutdown_function(function() {
  $err = error_get_last(); 

  if(!is_null($err)) {
     if ($err['type'] == E_ERROR || $err['type'] == E_CORE_ERROR) { // extend if you want
       // write to file..
     }
  }
}); 

// test it with
ini_set('max_execution_time', 1); 
sleep(5);
```

`$err['type']` can consist of constants defined on this page: [Error Handling > Predefined Constants](http://php.net/manual/en/errorfunc.constants.php)

For further information see: [Catching fatal errors in PHP](https://barelysufficient.org/2011/03/catching-fatal-errors-in-php/)

Comment: How does your code snippet differentiate between fatals and warnings?

Answer (score 0):

```
function my_error_handler($no, $str, $file, $line) {
    switch($no){
        case E_CORE_ERROR:    
            $e = new ErrorException($str, $no, 0, $file, $line);
            my_exception_handler($e);
            break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

According to PHP's documentation on [set_error_handler](http://php.net/manual/en/function.set-error-handler.php), the specified handler should be of the following form:

> *handler* ( int *$errno* , string *$errstr* [, string *$errfile* [, int *$errline* [, array *$errcontext* ]]] )
>
> (…)
>
> The first parameter, ***errno***, contains the level of the error raised, as an integer.

This means you should make your error handler this way:

```
<?php

function my_error_handler($errno, $errstr, $errfile, $errline, $errcontext) {
    // Only process fatal errors
    if ($errno == E_ERROR) {
        // Do your error processing
    }
}

set_error_handler('my_error_handler');

?>
```

Using this method you can precisely control how you handle each sort of error.

---

If you only want to process the fatal errors, you could do is much easier:

> mixed **set_error_handler** ( callable $error_handler [, int $error_types = E_ALL | E_STRICT ] )

The second parameter, `$error_types`, allows you to specify which errors should be processed with your custom error handler. You can just pass the `E_ERROR` constant, like this:

```
<?php

// Use your existing function

set_error_handler('my_error_handler', E_ERROR);

?>
```

Comment: Your logic makes sense but set_error_handler seems to ignore Fatal Errors, it catches everything but Fatal errors, by that I mean when a Fatal Error occurs, my_error_handler is not called, I'm using 5.2.13